# Create a date range based on rows but if date skips a day create another row

Tags: sql, reporting

I have a business requirement to show data from the following table.

[image]

I need a way thru SQL to show the data as...

[image]

So everytime the User_ID or SPOT or Date is skip in sequential order we create a new row.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Comment: Try searching for 'sql islands problem'

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, a solution might be:

```
with MyTbl as (
select *
from ( values 
 ('SomeOne1','A','2023-06-16')
,('SomeOne1','A','2023-06-17')
,('SomeOne1','A','2023-06-18')
,('SomeOne1','A','2023-06-19')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-20')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-21')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-22')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-23')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-24')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-25')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-26')
,('SomeOne1','B','2023-06-27')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-20')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-21')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-22')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-23')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-24')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-25')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-28')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-29')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-06-30')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-07-01')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-07-02')
,('SomeOneB','A','2023-07-03')
) T(UserId, Spot, this_Date)
), AssgnGrp as (
    select UserId, Spot, this_date
    ,  [Grp] = DATEADD(DAY,-1 * (DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by UserId, Spot ORDER BY [this_date])-1), [this_date])
    from MyTbl
)
select UserId, Spot, Grp, begin_date=min(this_date), end_date=max(this_date)
    from AssgnGrp
    group by UserId, Spot, Grp
```